# How do I integrate ASP.NET Membership in PHP sites?

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, drupal, membership

I am looking to use an open source CMS/blog site like WordPress or Drupal. I need it to work with the ASP.NET Membership I already have running my current website and community site.

I am assuming I need to muck with (hand write) some cookies to pass back and forth. So how would/have you done it? I am looking for creative ideas on how to make this happen smoothly and securely.

Comment: And no, I'm not looking to use a MySQL ASP.NET Membership Provider. I can't mod my Membership Provider in the ASP.NET site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal has a layered and pluggable [authentication system](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_login_default_validators/6), you can use that to connect to any external system for authentication.

As commentor points out below, "external system" may be a bit ambigous.

It does not have to be some XMLRPC, REST, or bus system, it can be anything, from a textfile in a directory to a table filled with legacy accounts in a "local" MySQL database. 
Point is, this pluggable authentication layer allows for any none Drupal-users-database-table to hook in an allow/disallow authentications/registrations.

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but he isn't really authenticating against an external system ... something tells me he doesn't mind hitting the local db for validation, it's just a matter of how does he go about it ... idk, maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: For Drupal, a none-drupal "local DB" counts as an "external system" nonetheless. Maybe I should've been more verbose, correcting that in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I query the database for the appropriate fields and I use this to create my cookies in C# code, does that help you?

```
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
           1,                            // version
           strUser,                      // user name
           DateTime.Now,                 // create time
           DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),     // expire time
           false,                        // persistent
           "my own data" );              // user data
        string strEncryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt( ticket );
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, strEncryptedTicket );
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add( cookie );
```

As for the queries to be run, those are straightforward and documented if you have an aspnetdb instance already up with an asp.net app using them, but I could post more code if you need some stuff for accessing those as well. You were asking about the cookie, so this is how I set my cookies in C#

Comment: I do this because I have two forms of authentication, but this works for the aspnetdb authentication elsewhere on my system. Once I set the cookie like this manually I'm done authing, and as you can see, it keeps for a year at a time (well yeah, of course you can set the exp time however you like)